# How to implement infinite scrolling with Swiper and RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js, rtk-query

I am trying to implement a simple infinite scroll in RTK Query together with swiper.js . I found that Stack Overflow discussion with a basic first implementation. However, I can't get it to run based on the instructions provided.

I have created a working example that illustrates my problem based on the Pokemon API. However there is basically a stop condition missing so it continuously fetches new pages. But i am struggling to implement it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-thunder-e3ntc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: react-window works fine for me whenever i need oo scroll.

Comment: is react-window supporting sliders / horizontal scroll?

Comment: just open the lib and check it (at list you will know about it - and you will find out that combination of letters bvaughn on a page usually means win-win).